# How To Store Multiple Checkbox Value In Database Using Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I'm new with laravel.

How to add subjects based on student id with checkbox form

[CREATE FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FiA8.png)

For example, when I select a student with id `3216` and add 2 subjects with id `105` and `106`, mysql will create 2 records like this.
[image]

Here is the code of views

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h9>Student ID</h9>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="student_id[]">
            @foreach($student as $stu)
                <option {{ $stu->id }}>{{ $stu->id }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <h9>Subject ID</h9>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        @foreach($subject as $su)
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject_id[]" value="{{ $su->id }}">
            <label for="cat_1">{{ $su->id }}</label><br/><br/>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->resultRepo->create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('result.index')->with('success', 'Successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail, what you are trying to achieve? You asked that you want to store multiple subjects, and again mentioned it is storing records. So, what is going wrong here, what is not working, could you please explain that in detail?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiple select

1. Get All selected value in array, in your case it is `subject_id[]`

```
$subjectIds = $request->subject_id
```

This will be an array

2. store them as json

```
$request->merge[
    'subject_id' => $subjectIds ? json_encode($subjectIds) : null,
];
```

3. Store them

```
$this->resultRepo->create($request->all());
```

4. And When You want to retrieve them

```
$data = YourModel::findOrFail($id);
$subjectIds = json_decode($data->subject_id)
dd($subjectIds);
```